# query not working for ordering by meta_key

Tags: wp-query

Here is my Query:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query(array(
    'post_type'=> array('music','yoga','demo_clinic', 'competition'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'thursday_time_p',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'meta_type'         => 'DATETIME',
    'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'private' ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'event_day', // your custom taxonomy
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'thursday' ) // the terms (categories) you created
        )
    )
));
```

But when I generate an SQL to see what is being queried, I get:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (59) ) AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'thursday_time_p' ) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('music', 'yoga', 'demo_clinic', 'competition') AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS DATETIME) ASC
```

So, for some reason it's ordering by Menu order???

Comment: Are you sure there are no actions attached to pre_get_posts hook, that modify the query?

Comment: That was it. Post Type Order plugin was installed.